# How can I query DynamoDB and return all child values for a specific key in an array

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in DynamoDB where each row has the following structure:

```
{
     "id": 1,
     "data": [
         {
             "key": "A",
             "value": "a"
         },
         {
             "key": "B",
             "value": "b"
         }
     ]
 },
 ...
```

I would like to create a query that returns a single row of data where the "value" keys have been filtered out of the results. Essentially, I am looking for a way to produce this output:

```
{
     "id": 1,
     "data": [
         {
             "key": "A"
         },
         {
             "key": "B"
         }
     ]
}
```

The trick is that the "data" list contains an unknown number of elements. Using the following code with Projection Expressions, I can get close to what I need in NodeJS:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = { 
    TableName: "MyTable",
    Key: {
        "id": 1
    },
    ProjectionExpression:"id, data[0].key"
};

docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

The code above returns the following data:

```
{
     "id": 1,
     "data": [
         {
             "key": "A"
         }
     ]
}
```

How can I get DynamoDB to return all the keys inside `data` and not just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported.

As I see it, you have two options:

- If there's an upper cap on number of entries in `data`, for e.g., 100, then you can modify your ProjectionExpression to something like: `"id, data[0].key, data[1].key, data[2].key, data[3].key, ..., data[100].key"`. It should work, because as per the [DynamoDB documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.AccessingItemAttributes.html#DocumentPaths), there is only one constraint on list indexes:

> The index in a list dereference must be a non-negative integer

- If there is no such upper cap, filter out on client-side.